# DB2 Stored Procedure IF statement

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I am currently experimenting with stored procedures and I am try to implement a simple IF/ELSE statement. I am using DB2 and I am trying to select all records if the procedure parameter is null and if the parameter is not null, query the database.

My stored procedure code is as follows:

```
    DROP PROCEDURE LWILSON.IFQUERY@
CREATE PROCEDURE LWILSON.IFQUERY
(
    IN p_type VARCHAR(15)
)

DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
DECLARE c_result CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
IF p_type IS NULL
THEN
SELECT * FROM LWILSON."ANIMALS";
OPEN c_result;
ELSE 
SELECT ID,TYPE,NAME,WEIGHT, AGE FROM LWILSON."ANIMALS" AS ANIMALRESULTS WHERE ANIMALRESULTS.type = p_type;
OPEN c_result;
END IF;
END@
```

(I am using the @ symbol for the command separator).
The error message I receive when trying to execute the procedure is as follows...
[image: Error message]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Don't think you can use `if .. else` with Cursor definition like that.

Comment: You need to declare two cursors and open one or the other.

Comment: I tried declaring another cursor below the stated one. I then opened the respective cursor and it still does not work. Any other suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by preparing the statement to execute. You do not need two cursors in this case:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LWILSON.IFQUERY (
    IN p_type VARCHAR(15)
)
  DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
  LANGUAGE SQL
 BEGIN
  DECLARE STMT VARCHAR(120);
  DECLARE c_result CURSOR
    WITH RETURN FOR RES_SET;

  IF (p_type IS NULL) THEN
   SET STMT = "SELECT * FROM LWILSON.ANIMALS";
  ELSE 
   SET STMT = "SELECT ID, TYPE, NAME, WEIGHT, AGE "
     || "FROM LWILSON.ANIMALS AS ANIMALRESULTS "
     || "WHERE ANIMALRESULTS.type = " || p_type;
  END IF;
  PREPARE RES_SET FROM STMT
  OPEN c_result;
 END@
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to make more sense. However, I get the following error.                                                 DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE= -104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC= p_type,ON.IF.QUERY(IN;,,DRIVER=3.57.110

Comment: The fix was adding escape characters around the parameter being entered....

In DB2 to get a single quote within a string you need to use double quotes ''

Comment: You did not specify the DB2 version. DB2 for LUW support that since version 9.7: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008329.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-12-7-90

Answer (score 1):

Best option I found was creating one cursor for each condition and opening the one you need.

```
DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR
    WITH RETURN FOR SELECT * FROM LWILSON.ANIMALS;
DECLARE cursor2 CURSOR
    WITH RETURN FOR SELECT * FROM LWILSON.ANIMALS AS ANIMALRESULTS
    WHERE ANIMALRESULTS.type = p_type;

IF (p_type IS NULL) THEN
    OPEN cursor1;
ELSE 
    OPEN cursor2;     
END IF;
```